# How to find hessian and gradient vector of a summation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m x n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_+$

$ \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} $ $f(x) = \frac \alpha2 ||x||_2^2 - \sum^m_{i=1} log(g_i(x)) $

where $g(x) = b - Ax$ and $g_i(x)$ is the i-th component of $g(x)$

Write the gradient vector and Hessian of $f$

I am pretty new to this an I don't really know how to start

Answer (score 1):

### How to calculate the gradient vector:

First I decompose $f(\mathbf{x}) = f_1(\mathbf{x}) = f_2(\mathbf{x})$ where
$$
f_1(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\alpha}{2}\left\lVert \mathbf{x} \right\rVert_2^2 
$$
and 
$$
f_2(\mathbf{x}) = - \sum_{i=1}^m h_i(\mathbf{x}) = -\sum_{i=1}^m \log (g_i(\mathbf{x})).
$$
For the first term the gradient is very nice
$$
\nabla f_1(\mathbf{x}) = \alpha \mathbf{x}
$$
and for the second we can write
$$
\nabla f_2(\mathbf{x}) = -\sum_{i=1}^m \nabla h_i(\mathbf{x})
$$
where $h_i(\mathbf{x}) = \log ([b - A x]_i) = \log (b_i - A_i x)$. We assume that $b_i > A_i x$ (if not our function is not defined) and note that
$$
\nabla (b_i - A_i x) = A_i
$$
Further recall that $(\log x)' = \frac{1}{x}$. Using this we can make use of the chain rule
$$
\nabla h_i(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{g_i(\mathbf{x})} \cdot \nabla g_i(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{g_i(\mathbf{x})} \cdot A_{i}
$$
where $A_{i}$ is the i'th row of $A$. Inserting everything back into our original function we arrive at
$$
\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \alpha \mathbf{x} - \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{A_i}{g_i(\mathbf{x})}
$$
Now this has perhaps given you a taste of the tools you need to use in such calculations and I am hoping you can use these tools to calculate the Hessian on your own.